# Symfony 4 extend request for validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony4

I'm currently working on an API project. I'm used to Laravel and now I need to work with Symfony. I want to use the request like Laravel does for validation. 
So I extend the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request class. There I made some logic to check and sanitize the incoming request.

After that I add my newly created request to the store function in the controller. But that gives me an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\Ticket\TicketController::store() must be an instance of App\Validation\Ticket\TicketStoreRequest, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given,/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 149 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to App\\Controller\\Ticket\\TicketController::store() must be an instance of App\\Validation\\Ticket\\TicketStoreRequest, instance of Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request given
```

After some googling, I found a few options.

1. Add every controller action to the service.yaml
2. Create a listener and add the validation on correct route

But all options require extra information on a different place. I hope someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few hints that might point you in the right direction:

> Symfony ships with five value resolvers in the HttpKernel component:
>
> ...
>
> **RequestValueResolver**
>
> Injects the current Request if type-hinted with Request or a class extending Request.

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html

Then the page goes on to describe the implementation of a custom RequestAttributeValueResolver. This custom resolver can be registered in your 
`services.yml`. 
Though in this example a single Class is created for one single attribute type (User), there are ways to create a more dynamic implementation.

In this example the `ArgumentMetadata` parameter has a method `$argument->getType()` that should contain a string representation of the type that is checked against:

```
if (User::class !== $argument->getType()) {
    return false;
}
```

Nothing is stopping you from checking against an array of supported Request-types. This array can be managed as a class member in your custom `RequestValueResolver`. The only requirement for your custom `RequestValueResolver` class, is that the `supports()` method returns `true` for supported Request types, and that the `resolve()` function returns an instance of this supported Request type. This should be straightforward because both methods are supplied the 'desired' class through the `ArgumentMetaData` parameter.

As an alternative, you can implement a custom `RequestValueResolver` for each custom Request type you want to support, but this does not feel very elegant.

I can not guarantee this will work and I'm also not sure about the differences between implementing the `RequestAttributeValueResolver` in the example and implementing a custom `RequestValueResolver`, but I have a feeling it might just work, with a bit of elbow grease.

For reference: https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver/RequestValueResolver.html

Comment: I still have to create an entry for every route.

Comment: Accepted this answer as best answer, because there seems to be no better solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that elaborates on my other example. It's not as *secure* as my other example, but it satisfies your requirements.

```
public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
{    
    $desiredRequestClass = $argument->getType();

    return class_exists($desiredRequestClass);
}

public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument)
{
    $desiredRequestClass = $argument->getType();
    $customRequest = new $desiredRequestClass();

    $customRequest->createFromGlobals();
    // TODO: more initialization you might need.

    yield $customRequest;
}
```

It might be advisable to check if `$desiredRequestClass` is a descendant of `Request`.